# How to solve error MSB3721 when DeBug in a ARM64X64 way?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging, umdf, windows-arm64

My Environment as follow:

- Host OS : Macbook Air M1;
- VM OS: Windows-10-21H2, VS2019,in Parallels Desktop 18
- VS2019

I have got the following errors, when I DeBug my first UMDF windows driver.

`1>------ 已启动全部重新生成: 项目: USBUMDF2Driver1, 配置: Debug ARM64 ------ 1>Building 'USBUMDF2Driver1' with toolset 'WindowsUserModeDriver10.0' and the 'Universal' target platform. 1>Stamping ARM64\Debug\USBUMDF2Driver1.inf 1>Stamping [Version] section with DriverVer=11/21/2023,17.17.0.232 1>Device.c 1>Driver.c 1>Queue.c 1>  Building Library C:\Users\hewenyong\source\repos\USBUMDF2Driver1\ARM64\Debug\USBUMDF2Driver1.lib 和对象 C:\Users\hewenyong\source\repos\USBUMDF2Driver1\ARM64\Debug\USBUMDF2Driver1.exp 1>正在生成代码 1>已完成代码的生成 1>USBUMDF2Driver1.vcxproj -> C:\Users\hewenyong\source\repos\USBUMDF2Driver1\ARM64\Debug\USBUMDF2Driver1.dll 1>Done Adding Additional Store 1>Successfully signed: C:\Users\hewenyong\source\repos\USBUMDF2Driver1\ARM64\Debug\USBUMDF2Driver1.dll 1> 1>ApiValidation : error : While Checking file C:\Users\hewenyong\source\repos\USBUMDF2Driver1\ARM64\Debug\USBUMDF2Driver1.dll aitstatic is returned exit code 216. 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.common.targets(1794,5): error MSB3721: 命令“"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\ApiValidator.exe" -DriverPackagePath:C:\Users\hewenyong\source\repos\USBUMDF2Driver1\ARM64\Debug\USBUMDF2Driver1.dll -SupportedApiXmlFiles:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\universalDDIs\arm64\UniversalDDIs.xml" -ModuleWhiteListXmlFiles:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\universalDDIs\arm64\ModuleWhiteList.xml" -ApiExtractorExePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86"”exited，return code -1. 1>已完成生成项目“USBUMDF2Driver1.vcxproj”的操作 - 失败。`

The error lists as following:

`

MSB3721 命令“"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64\ApiValidator.exe" -DriverPackagePath:C:\Users\hewenyong\source\repos\USBUMDF2Driver1\ARM64\Debug\USBUMDF2Driver1.dll -SupportedApiXmlFiles:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\universalDDIs\arm64\UniversalDDIs.xml" -ModuleWhiteListXmlFiles:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\universalDDIs\arm64\ModuleWhiteList.xml" -ApiExtractorExePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86"” exited，return code -1.  USBUMDF2Driver1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\build\WindowsDriver.common.targets   1794
`

I have try change to X86, it work,but I need Arm64 and x64.

Can anyone tell me what is this and how can I solve it?

Comment: That's ERROR_EXE_MACHINE_TYPE_MISMATCH.  For some reason you're running x64\ApiValidator.exe, it isn't happy about having to validate an arm64 image.

Comment: Yeah，now i have change my work environment to x64 PC，it is easy to install anything.
I guess, Microsoft not work well on arm64 for WDK, it can not bypass the sign validate, and it just support for arm64 VScode2022 but not wdk.

Thank you for your answer, my friend.